# Performing actions on single or multiple rows of table

Tags: html

I got a table with some columns of a database record in each row. Each of these columns is editable and multiple actions can be performed on the record. This would be easy to do in HTML, just wrapping each row in a separate form.

However, it should also be possible to perform actions on multiple rows selected by checkboxes.

[image: .]

What is the best way to allow these single-row actions (while preferably not submitting all the other rows) and multi-row actions in the same table using HTML (preferably without js)?

Comment: Please state how I can improve the question if downvoting. I tried to demonstrate it as good as possible.

Comment: Start with _"Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code."_

Comment: All related code should _always_ be included in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use only one form, than for each record use an array, where first coordinate is your item ID from database, as following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id[2]" />
<input type="text" name="column1[2]" />
<input type="text" name="column2[2]" />
```

Later on you can post the form, or serialize it and use ajax. If you do not want to use checkboxes, but to change values on the fly, than remove them (checkboxes) and insert hidden fields with old values (so you can compare). In order to detect which submit button has been used, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465886/determining-which-submit-button-was-used)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- Have a single `<form>` element that wraps the entire table.
- When any of the action buttons is pressed, use JavaScript to prevent default action and construct `FormData` dynamically (based on which button was pressed) and submit via Ajax.
- The fallback (i.e. if JavaScript execution fails) submits the entire table. On the server-side, detect this case and extract the relevant data, then proceed normally (like if submitted via Ajax).